# Is possible that Ext.util.JSON.encode return an undefined value?

Tags: javascript, extjs, json

I have a problem with an undefined value from a request and I can't reproduce this issue.

Ext.util.JSON.encode can return an undefined value?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the input and the output ?

Answer (score 0):

yes its only possible when you do `JSON.stringify(undefined);` if you do `JSON.stringify({a : undefined})` then it will just remove the key value pair with undefined value so it will give you a blank object

please check if the problem is in ExtJs or you are passing malformed JSON object, to verify this you can use native JSON parser provided in latest browsers, so in FF or Chrome you can set
`Ext.USE_NATIVE_JSON = false`, before your application starts and see if you still have the error this config will tell ExtJs to use native implementation of JSON of browsers